# Realtime Javascript synth on Android/IOS. HTML5 audio tag won't take injected data

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio, synthesizer

I have an Javascript application that creates some audio tones and plays them. The tones are generated as a WAV file then injected like this....

```
<audio id="player" controls autobuffer="autobuffer" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  document.getElementById("player").src = wavData;
  document.getElementById("player").play();
</script>
```

This works on recent versions of Chrome or Firefox on a PC but not on any mobile device I tried including Android 4.0.3, Android 2.3 and an IPhone.

Another example of a Javascript synth that works on a desktop but not an Android device is this "Morning Star" synth.
http://bitterspring.net/ms/morningstar/

An example of HTML5 audio that *does* work on Android is this test page. http://textopia.org/androidsoundformats.html .

Is there a workaround? I want a solution based entirely on HTML/Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MorningStar author here: my synth *does not* use any `<audio>` tag, it uses Web Audio API.

I haven't tested it on Android devices (yet), but if the stock Android browser doesn't support Web Audio API, there's no way the synth could work.

Comment: I recently ported my synth to javascript ([take a look](http://bmxplay.sourceforge.net/)) but I'm not sure, that I use the best method for streaming. May I use some kind of a stream object with data callback instead of scheduling and recreating audio nodes (createBufferSource) every 250 ms? Maybe there's a more "proper" way?

Answer (score 0):

Android 2.3 does not have good support for the  tag.  One solution is to do is use flash on android.

this might help.
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Although Soundmanager is really useful it didn't solve my problem. I was unable to pass WAV data to it from Javascript.